# Where am I not Threadsafe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm using an object, which serves roughly as a wrapper for a map of Strings:

```
public class Wrapper {
  private Map<String, String> values;
  private Formatter formatter;

  public BigDecimal getSpecialValue() {
    String result = values.get("Special");
    return formatter.formatNumber(result);
  }
}
```

The abovementioned formatter serves roughly as a mapper for a SimpleDateFormat

```
 public class Formatter {
   private static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT;

   public BigDecimal formatNumber(String s) {
     Number num = NUMBER_FORMAT.parse(s);
     if (num instanceof Integer) {
       return new BigDecimal((Integer) num);
     } else if (num instanceof Double) {
       return new BigDecimal((Double) num);
     } ...
   }
 }
```

When I access the `getSpecialValue()` method by several threads at once, some behaviour accurs, which can only be explained by the concurrent access, for example there may be a `NumberFormatException` or a `ParseException` where the parsed string is .430.430 instead of .430 and so on.

There are two aspects which arouse my interest:
1.) The wrapper is only accessed read-only. Although access to the collection is not synchronized, I was under the impression that this should always work.
2.) In one of the first attempts to find the problem I changed the constructor of the `Wrapper` class to execute the `formatNumber` method (obviously single threaded), which eliminated all Exceptions down the execution.

Can someone explain?

Edit: 
The map in the `Wrapper` class is filled in the constructor, which most definitly happens single threaded. Afterwards the wrapper is designed such that the map is immutable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just searching the jdoc for "thread" would've found you the following for the NumberFormat class: `Number formats are generally not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.`

Comment: @Nate Yep the obvious solution (and would be the first time for me ever to use `ThreadLocal` - that gives plus points for being exotic!) . Although it depends on how often it is accessed and so on. Creating a new instance for each thread if it uses it only once could be less efficient than some locking.

Comment: Understood and accepted. I was not reading the javadoc, I was however browsing the NumberFormat (and child-classes) source code and have not discovered any member-variables which could explain, why NumberFormat is not threadsafe. Could a class be not-threadsafe even if its member-variables were accessed read-only?

Comment: @Jonathan Even if the current implementation may be thread-safe, if it's documented to NOT be you shouldn't rely on it. Reading source code instead of the documentation is a really bad idea if you want to understand an API for exactly that reason. And a quick look at `DecimalFormat` shows quite a lot of instance variables whose interaction isn't completely clear to me.. also since you do get strange behavior when printing some kind of interaction obviously does happen ;) (you could trace the call carefully if you wanted to find out what exactly goes wrong)

Comment: But to answer your question: If no writes AND reads to non-finals (writes alone isn't enough, what is if you read some variables while another thread writes to them? You could easily end up with inconsistencies) happen it'd be thread-safe, yes. Sidenote that may be of interest: Immutability does not necessarily mean thread-safe either. It usually does (and I'd consider anything else bad design), but there are exceptions. There could be a shared cache internally for example - I actually think some DateTime classes in java do that..

Answer (score 1):

1. NumberFormat is not thread-safe. So storing it in a static variable and use it from multiple threads will lead to problems. Either synchronize every use of this object, or store it in a ThreadLocal variable.
2. Even if the wrapper is only accessed read-only, there must be some time where the map of values is initialized and populated, and where the formatter is created, else there wouldn't be anything to format. You didn't show the real, complete code of the class, so you might have at least visibility problems in this class as well.